# When is it ok to use a sequential limit in place of a continuous limit?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am working through some Lebesgue integral problems, and I've come across a few instances where I would like to use the dominated/monotone convergence theorems, but the limit is continuous, and I'm not sure if it is ok to switch to sequential limits. For example, a problem I am working on is:

Let $E$ be Lebesgue-measurable, $f \in L^1(E)$, and suppose $f > 0$ a.e. on $E$. Show that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int |f(x)|^{1/k}\ dm = m(E).$$

I would like to let $A = \{x : f(x) \ge 1\}$, and integrate over $A$ and $A^c$, respectively. Then, it seems natural to use the DCT on $A$ and the MCT on $A^c$ to pull the limit inside of the integrals. But, I know the DCT/MCT only work on countable sequences of functions, and I'm not sure of what reasoning I should give for being able to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} = \lim_{k\to\infty}$, where $n \in N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prove that $$\lim_{j \to \infty} \int |f(x)|^{1/k_j} \, dm = m(E)$$ for every sequence $\{k_j\}$ that diverges to $\infty$. This is equivalent to the continuous limit equaling $m(E)$.